# How to properly freeze layers of a pretrained pytorch CNN and declare this in the optimizer

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Pytorch: How to properly freeze layers of pretrained CNN and set the parameter accordingly in torch.optim

Hello guys,

I am working with `Pytorch` and want to use a pretrained CNN to solve a classification problem. The classification problem is a multi-output one, meaning that I have three classification layers.

My goal is to freeze all layers of a pretrained pytorch CNN (e.g. Alexnet), add my classification layers and enable param.requires_grad = True for them.

I intialized the CNN with this bit of code:

```
class CNN1(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, pretrained):
    super(CNN1, self).__init__()
    if pretrained is True:
        self.model = models.__dict__["alexnet"](pretrained="imagenet")
    else:
        self.model = models.__dict__["alexnet"](pretrained=None)
    self.Arousal= nn.Linear(256, 10)
    self.Valence = nn.Linear(256,10)
    self.Dominance = nn.Linear(256, 10)    
    
def forward(self, x):
    bs, _, _, _ = x.shape
    x = self.model.features(x)
    x = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(x, 1).reshape(bs, -1)
    Arousal = self.Arousal(x)
    Valence = self.Valence(x)
    Dominance = self.Dominance(x)
    return Arousal, Valence, Dominance 
    return {'label1': label1, 'label2': label2, 'label3': label3}
```

and then freeze/unfreeze layers by doing this:

```
model_CNN = CNN1(True).to(device)

for param in model_CNN.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
for param in model_CNN.Arousal.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
for param in model_CNN.Valence.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
for param in model_CNN.Dominance.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True
```

However, I am not sure if this actually working. When printing the model, it says param.requires_grad =True/False correctly for the respective layers.

In my training loop I intialized the optimizer like that:

```
def train(net, loss_fn, dataloader_train,dataloader_val,
      epoch=100, learning_rate=0.0001):
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

How can I check if the code is actually working, i.e. if only the last three layers are trained?

Kind regards